# How to show that a particular sequence is always above a certain value?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, radicals

I am trying to solve the following question but I am a little confused on how to solve it. The question is the following:

$x_{n+1} = \frac{x_{n}}{2} + \frac{a}{2x_{n}}, x_{0} = r >0, r \in Q, a > 0$.

I need to show that $x^{2}_{n} > a  \forall n \ge 1$ . I am a little confused on how to do this, since what I essentially did was express $x^{2}_{n} = \frac{1}{4}x^{2}_{n-1} + a^{2}\frac{1}{4x_{n-1}^{2}} + \frac{a}{2}$.

But I have no clue what to do from here on forth.

Like this shows that the $x_{n}^{2}$ is definitely at least greater than a/2. But how can I show that it is greater than a?

Also, I was trying to show that $x_{n} > x_{n+1}  \forall n \ge 1$. I am so confused on how to do this as well. I tried to prove this using induction but really could not get to an end result. If I split up the $x_{n+1}$ term I get that each term individually is less than $x_{n}$. But how can I cummulatively show that it is less than $x_{n}$?

Finally, I was asked to conclude using the two solutions above that $x_{n} -> L$ where $L^{2} = a$

I have no idea how to even get started on this part.

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean?

Comment: No I don't actually. How can I use it here? Can you help?

Comment: I am wondering if this can be solved in arithmetic-geometric inequality since the book that I am using does not cover this topic and poses the question before covering it.

Comment: You can write $x^{2}_{n} - a = \frac{1}{4}x^{2}_{n-1} + a^{2}\frac{1}{4x_{n-1}^{2}} - \frac{a}{2}$ as a square ...

Comment: Got it! This makes sense!  Is there a similar way to prove that $x_{n+1} \le x_{n}$?

Comment: Write down $\frac{x_{n}}{2} + \frac{a}{2x_{n}} \le x_n$ and simplify it. Use that you already proved $x_n^2 > a$.

Comment: Got you! Thanks! How can I use all these to now make a conclusion about the limit? I am getting confused because I don't understand how to prove these things without having the definition for the square root of a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x_0^2 = a$ then $x_n^2 = a$ for all $n$, i.e. the sequence is constant.

Otherwise
$$
 x_{n+1}^2 - a = \frac{1}{4}x^{2}_{n} + a^{2}\frac{1}{4x_{n}^{2}} - \frac{a}{2}
= \left( \frac{x_n}{2}- \frac{a}{2x_n}\right)^2
= \frac{(x_n^2 -a)^2}{4x_n^2}
$$
shows that $x_n^2 > a$ for all $n \ge 1$. Then
$$
x_{n+1} - x_n = -\frac{x_{n}}{2} + \frac{a}{2x_{n}} = - \frac{x_n^2-a}{2x_n} < 0
$$
shows that $x_{n+1} < x_n$ for $n \ge 1$.

So you have a decreasing sequence which is bounded below, and that is convergent by the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), i.e. $L = \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$ exists.

Finally use the recursion formula to show that $L$ satisfies
$$
 L = \frac L2 + \frac{a}{2L}
$$
and conclude that $L^2=a$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : (0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined for all $x > 0$ by
$$f(x)= \frac{x}{2} + \frac{a}{2x}$$

$f$ is differentiable on $(0, +\infty)$ and for all $x > 0$,
$$f'(x)= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{a}{2x^2}$$

so $f'(x) \geq 0$ iff $x \geq \sqrt{a}$. You deduce that $f$ attains its minimum at $x=\sqrt{a}$, so for all $y > 0$,
$$f(y) \geq f(\sqrt{a})= \frac{\sqrt{a}}{2} + \frac{a}{2\sqrt{a}} = \sqrt{a}$$

In particular, for all $n \geq 1$, $x_n = f(x_{n-1}) \geq \sqrt{a}$, so you deduce that
$$x_n^2 \geq a$$

Comment: Hey, so I am not sure if I can use differentiation for this question, because this question was actually given to define what sqrt(a) means. So if I end up using what it means to define it, it kinds defeats the purpose!

Comment: @user1234 It would be highly inappropriate conceptually to have this convergent sequence business as the definition of what ''the square root of $a$ means". We have a very clear and simple algebraic definition for that, namely any *positive* real number $b$ such that $b^2=a$. One easily proves that there is *at most* one $b$ satisfying this, in other words that if the square root exists it is unique. One could resort to the convergent sequence in question to infer *the existence* of the square root but not to serve as a definition for the square root.